# Redundant parentheses in the declarator of a variable with deduced class template specialization type

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, ctad

The following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/orKE9n8P1)

```
template <typename = int>
struct S {};

S (s);
```

is compiled by GCC with only a warning about the redundant parentheses around the declarator. However, Clang gives a hard error for the declaration

> error: cannot use parentheses when declaring variable with deduced class template specialization type

This is quite a specific error (e.g. `S<int> (s);` compiles), so I guess this is intentional, but I can't find the wording that says this is ill-formed. Obvious candidates like [dcl.dcl](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl) and [temp.class.general](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.general) don't say anything about this, unless I missed it.

Is this a GCC bug, or is it IFNDR, and Clang is being helpful?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be Clang over-eagerly applying [CWG2376](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2376) by prohibiting *all* declarator operators rather than just those that change the type declared.  Heuristics for diagnosing most-vexing-parse issues might also be at play.